# With Haskell/Parsec, how to parse strings which encode their own length?

Tags: haskell, parsec

I'm trying to parse a string of binary digits with Haskell and Parsec. The binary string is divided into variable length *packets*. A packet can either encode an integer value or again a bunch of sub-packets. Let's say the first bit tells us what kind of packet it is. `1` means value; `0` means sub-packets. The following 10 bits tell us the remaining length of the packet. So each packet has a fixed length header (11 bits) and a variable length body.

For me the tricky part is, how to define a `Parser` in terms of other parsers but fix the amount of consumed characters to a number I dynamically obtained **during** parsing (the body length).

I came up with a solution but I have a feeling that this is not best practice:

```hs
data Packet = Value Int | SubPackets [Packet]

binaryDigit :: Parser Char
binaryDigit = char '0' <|> char '1'

packet :: Parser Packet
packet = do
    isValue <- binaryDigit
    packetBody isValue

packetBody :: Char -> Parser Packet
-- body encodes value
packetBody '1' = do
    bodyLength <- binToInt <$> count 10 binaryDigit
    body <- count bodyLength binaryDigit
    return $ Value (binToInt body)
-- body encodes sub packages
packetBody '0' = do
    bodyLength <- binToInt <$> count 10 binaryDigit
    body <- count bodyLength binaryDigit
    -- is this best practice? :
    case parse (many packet <* eof) "" body of
        Right packets -> return $ SubPackets packets
        Left parseError -> unexpected (show parseError)    

binToInt :: [Char] -> Int
binToInt [] = 0
binToInt (x:xs) = (digitToInt x) * 2 ^ length xs + binToDec xs
```

You see in the second case of `parseBody`, instead of defining a `Parser` for the sub-packets, I directly use `parse`. Especially the error handling strikes me as a bit ugly.

Comment: Heh. https://adventofcode.com/2021/day/16 stirred up a lot of questions like this. Parsec-likes just aren't built for this. Binary parsers like the binary or cereal packages are a lot more capable in this context, with their `isolate` combinator.

Comment: I've done similar things by running not just `Parser`, but `StateT _ Parser`. In this case, I think, the state might be the remaining length.

Comment: @Carl you got me :) anyway, I don't need a perfect tool. I mainly want to understand Parsec better.

Answer (score 3):

As Carl mentions, this is a limitation of megaparsec that occurs commonly when parsing binary formats. I'm not quite sure off-hand how much work it would be to define an appropriate combinator for this.

However for this case at least, one solution is to poll the current offset before and/or after each subpacket.

```hs
packetBody '0' = do
    bodyLength <- binToInt <$> count 10 binaryDigit
    start <- getOffset
    let checkOffset = do
          new <- getOffset
          if new < start + bodyLength then pure () else empty
    SubPackets <$> many (checkOffset *> packet)
```

This only checks whether there is room left before reading the next packet, so you might read a packet past the expected length. To avoid that, you can do the check after each packet, or you can add an extra branch in `checkOffset` with an irrecoverable failure if `new > start + bodyLength` (which involves using `ParsecT` not on `Identity` but on a monad with its own failures).